# Bad syntax in popular python library

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to use the mitmproxy Python API but the line `from mitmproxy import http` gives a syntax error. The ["http" module](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/http.py) contains lines like

```
self.request: HTTPRequest = None
```

and

```
def make_error_response(
        status_code: int,
        message: str="",
        headers: Optional[http.Headers]=None,
) -> HTTPResponse:
    reason = http.status_codes.RESPONSES.get(status_code, "Unknown")
```

which don't look like Python.

Am I missing something, or is this just bad code?

Comment: this is type annotations you need to use `python3`

Comment: Your code works for me, make sure you are using Python 3 as suggested by @zimdero

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [mitmproxy docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/), you will need to have the most recent Python version.

> Please make sure to install Python 3.6 (or higher) and pip3 for your distribution.

What you are seeing are [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) which have been added in Python 3.5.